# Is the problem of cryonics only the pressure?

Tags: cell-biology, cryonics

According to the pop-sci sources which I drew on from, the only problem with freezing whole bodies its that you can't conserve it without freeze-damage.

If you were keeping a cold-blooded animal in a cold surrounding (well, before that removed the parasites somehow) and optimized the pressure in there so to make the cells not to collapse, could you stop all its functions and bring it back to life again later?

Comment: Lobsters sometimes wake up after being frozen alive...

Comment: @vervet wow...that seems like the problems are mostly about the parasites contained in water (that you should just drain out) - I really do not know anything about lobsters, but compared to other animals the main difference is outter skeleton (it could work as an antiinfective protective cover)...is it so?

Comment: "The parasites contained in water"? Could you elaborate? (I suspect part of the reason lobsters have an easier time is their semi-open circulatory systems. Lobsters can't die of internal bleeding.)

Comment: @Resonating Interesting indeed, I will look at that. About the parasites: Easier forms of life often survive harder conditions. But originally I wrote it because I said to myself that food in the fridge rot as well, but slower - that's not true for negative temperatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem in cryonics is that when an organism is frozen, all of the organism starts freezing. The cell start expanding since ice expands too. The sharp edges of the ice crystals can destroy a lot. Also, your blood would freeze. Again, the sharp edges of the ice crystals would destroy major blood vessels. That is why currently, they have to insert antifreeze into the blood, but it still might not be effective.

Now, to answer your question, many cold-blooded organisms can survive freezing cold temperatures. Some frogs (like the wood frog), for example, have anti-freeze in their blood vessels! So some actually have special adaptations to survive freezing cold temperatures.

I hope this answered your question. Please ask in the comments if you want more information on this. I will gladly research up for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's about how I had imagined it. So is it so we really can handle all the other problems nowadays? And about the cold-blodded - they have some kind of salt to keep the blood liquid in colder temperatures, haven't they? ([conifers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d260CmZoxj8) and [embryonal-cryonics](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/32nas3/why_can_we_freeze_eggs_and_embryos_but_not_humans/) definitely uses this technique)

Comment: @Probably yes,you are correct. Remember, if you like my answer, you can accept it